# Define model with Array of another Object

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trainning in Python 3.6 and I am Typescript Developper. I try to learn and undestand by himself.

I want create a model with structural type, with small "Cashier" exercise.

I have an error like `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'chart_list'`

ChartModel.py

```py
class ChartModel:

    def __init__(
            self,
            person: Person,
            chart_list: [Product]
    ):
        self.person = person
        self.chart_list = chart_list

    @staticmethod
    def get_attributes():
        return ChartModel.__dict__
```

Product.py

```py
class Product:

    def __init__(self, name: str, price_by_unit: float, number: int):
        self.number = number
        self.price_by_unit = price_by_unit
        self.name = name

    @staticmethod
    def get_attributes():
        return Product.__dict__
```

My cash register class is a file where I put all logical of operation "Add to chart", "Remove to chart" etc.

```py
from model.chart import ChartModel
from model.product import Product

from decimal import *


class CashRegister:

    total_chart: float
    currency: str

    def __init__(self, chart: ChartModel, currency = "€"):
        getcontext().prec = 4
        self.chart = chart,
        self.currency = currency

    def calculate_chart(self):
        chart_list = self.chart.chart_list
        result = 0

        for item in chart_list:
            result += Decimal(item.number) * Decimal(item.price_by_unit)

        self.total_chart = result

    def add_to_chart(self, product: Product):
        self.chart.chart_list.append(product)
        self.calculate_chart()
        return self.chart.chart_list

    def get_attributes(self):
        chart = []

        for item in self.chart.chart_list:
            chart.append(item)

        result = {
            chart,
            self.total_chart,
            self.currency,
            self.chart.chart_list,
            self.chart.person
        }

        return result
```

And this class is called in **__init__.py**:

```py
from model.chart import ChartModel
from model.person import Person
from model.product import Product
from loop import Loop
from cashRegister import CashRegister

class FirstClass:

    def __init__(self):

        session = CashRegister(
            ChartModel(
                Person("My First Name", "My Last Name", True, True),
                []
            )
        )

        session.add_to_chart(
            Product("Cucumber", 0.65, 2)
        )

        print(session.get_attributes())

FirstClass()
```

I have many errors from interpreter as follow:

```
File "__init__.py", line 24, in __init__
    Product("Cucumber", 0.65, 2)
```

I don't understand this error, I inform with good object.

And it return an error at next:

```
File "CashRegister.py", line 27, in add_to_chart
    self.chart.chart_list.append(product)
```

Reason:

```
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'chart_list'
```

I'm slightly frustrated, don't understand why python don't takes my "Product" Object.

I have many questions:

1. Anyone have an explanation ?
2. It's a good idea to want typed with Python ?
3. What's is good practise with python in form documentation and unit test ?

Comment: Likely your issue is here: `self.chart = chart,`
The extra comma turns that into a tuple. Try removing that as a starting point